# Auto Incremented column start with first char of Name, month(09), then four digits

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Auto Incremented column start with first character of Name, month(09), then four digits that are incremented automatically .
(for "Transworld"-August-08-stock number is 1): T080001

using C# and Enitity framework. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Does the last part increment every time or just when the letter and month are the same.  For instance if you then add something with the letter A and month 1 would it be A010002 or would it be A010001?  In general it would be best to keep these values separate in the DB and only combine them for display or maybe you can explain why you need this configuration in your DB.

Comment: @kashif you can modify according to your requirement,Please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this recently and I found no inbuilt way. So what I did was

- Get the latest entry to the db (assuming your entries have an id or a date input that you can sort by and get the top one)
- Get substring starting from the 3rd character
- Parse the string to a number
- increment your number
- create your new inventory number with digit you extracted

you will have to be aware of concurrency issue where two requests could get T08001 and it would add T08002 into the db twice

Answer (score 0):

Create Table BillComment( ClientCode char(25), BillCommentSeq smallint)
DECLARE @ClientCode char(20), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Mnth Int

SELECT @BillCommentSeq=Max(BillCommentSeq) FROM billcomment
     IF @BillCommentSeq Is NUll
     SET @BillCommentSeq=1
     Else
     Select @BillCommentSeq = Max(BillCommentSeq) + 1 FROM billcomment 
      Set @Mnth=DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())

Set
@ClientCode ='A0'+Convert(Varchar(20),@Mnth)+'000'+Convert(varchar(15),@BillCommentSeq)
INSERT into BillComment
Select @ClientCode,@BillCommentSeq

Comment: Try To Generate The Number from SQL

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have done. This has some issues but for now it's working properly.

```
var maxStockId = stockv.Max(x => x.Id);
var stockGetWithId = stockv.Find(x => x.Id == maxStockId);
var SystemStockNo = stockGetWithId.SystemStockNo;
if (SystemStockNo != null && SystemStockNo.Length == 7)
{
var lastFourDigits = SystemStockNo.Substring(SystemStockNo.Length - 4);
var incrementlastFourDigits = Numerics.GetInt(lastFourDigits) + 1;
var newStockNoWithZeros = string.Format("{0:0000}", incrementlastFourDigits);
st.SystemStockNo = customerCompanyName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + newStockNoWithZeros.ToString();
}
else
{
st.SystemStockNo = customerCompanyName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "0001";
}
```